# Dirichlet density with just one x value and one alpha parameter

Tags: r, distributions, density-function, dirichlet-distribution

Does it make any sense to apply the Dirichlet density function to only one x value and therefore one alpha parameter?  (this would be the result of some bin merging)

I'm asking because it appears that gtool's implementation always returns 0 in such case, whereas [this implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658866/calculating-pdf-of-dirichlet-distribution-in-python) doesn't. And this is the only case where their output they differs.

```
x=[0.94736842105263153]; 
alphas = [0.032034681077891182]
======> implementation 1: 1.05372888806 ; 
======> gtool implementation: 0.
```

I'm very tempted to declare this result as non valid and re-merge bins differently.

Comment: The Wikipedia article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution points out that the x's are constrained to lie on a $K-1$ dimensional simplex: in the present case, with $K=1$, that limits $x$ to the sole value of $1$.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So whenever it's not 1 and there's only one x the probability of that to happen is 0, hence the result from gtool. Did I get this right?